# Variable set inside while loop is not visible outside

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

Variable $adsQ is an output of sql. This variable has number of lines in matrix format. When I pass this variable with pipe to while loop, it works fine whereas I loose variable required from while loop. As suggested from other forums, I modified with followings

```
            varout=''
            while IFS= read -r adrow;
            do
                    <... do something....>
                    varout="$varout $adrow"
            done < <(printf '%s\n' $adsQ)
            echo "output of while $varout"
            echo "AFTER adsVal >> $adsVal"
```

when I run this, i get error stating

test.sh: line 72: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
test.sh: line 72:`     done < <(printf '%s\n' $adsQ)'

Comment: You are running the script with a shell that does not support process substitution, not `bash`.

Comment: What shell are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extraneous `<` in your command. You wrote

```
done < <(...)
```

Remove the first `<`.